# Some group theory interpretion problem

Tags: group-theory

Very simple question I think, but I can't fully understand the following set:

We are given a group $G$ with a subgroup $H$. Then I have to answer some questions about the subgroup $$\bigcap_{g\in G} gHg^{-1}$$

Wat exactly are the elements of this group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That subgroup is called "the core" of the subgroup $\,H\le G\,$ , and it's characterizied for being the maximal normal subgroup of $\,G\,$ which is contained in $\,H\,$.

You can get it as follows: let $\,g\cdot (xH)\mapsto (gx)H\;$ be the left regular action of $\,G\, $ on the set $\;X\;$ of left cosets of $\,H\, $ in $\,G\,$ . As with any other group action on a set, this one determines a group homomorphism $\,G\to \text{Sym}_X\;$ ( note, for example, that if $\;[G:H]=n\;$ then $\,\text{Sym}_X\cong S_n\;$).

Well, the core of $\,H\,$ is *precisely* the kernel of this homomorphism...

Comment: $\large{+1}{}{}$

Answer (score 2):

The subgroup is the intersection of the subgroups $gHg^{-1}$. If $\{A_i\}_{i \in I}$ is some collection of sets (indexed by $I$), then

$$\bigcap_{i \in I} A_i$$

denotes the set of those elements that are contained in every $A_i$. Thus your subgroup consists of those elements of $G$ that are contained in $gHg^{-1}$ for every $g \in G$.

Answer (score 1):

The group is also known as core$_G(H)$ and is the largest *normal* subgroup of $G$ contained in $H$.